# filtering orders by phone makes duplicated orders (a visualisation problem)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I Created a prestashop module that allow the admin to search order by the phone number. But unforchently, it duplicates in the orders page. There is no duplication inside the database it's just a visualisation problem.

here is my code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vtURm308463iM4tMi2oKVQAB9L0cOZj5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You are joining with address table, using the id_customer.
That way, you get a result for each address related to the customer who did the order.
I mean, each order will appear as many times as addresses has the customer.

To avoid this, you can join using id_delivery_address instead of id_customer.
So you only will get the delivery address, that can be only one.
And I think the interesting phone is from the delivery address.

I edited your file, just line 66, changed:

```
'abc.`id_customer` = o.`id_customer`'
```

to:

```
'abc.`id_address` = o.`id_address_delivery`'
```

If you need to filter searching a phone in any address related to customer owner of the order, let me know.

Comment: yes this is was the problem thx for help :)